# change all checkboxes in one table-row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I want to uncheck all checkboxes that are in one table row. 
I have this HTML code :

```
<tr id="unlosta_line_1">
     <td>
        <input id="unlosta_prop_id_1" name="unlosta_prop_id[1]" value="1"  checked="checked" type="checkbox">
Feld 1
     </td>

     <td>
        <input id="unlosta_prop_id_2" name="unlosta_prop_id[2]" value="2"  type="checkbox">
Feld 2
     </td>

     <td>
        <input id="unlosta_prop_id_3" name="unlosta_prop_id[3]" value="3"  type="checkbox">
Feld 3
     </td>
     <td>...and so on
     <td>
</tr>
```

What I have tried at now is this jquery code:

```
$("tr#unlosta_line_1").children("td").each(function(i) { $(i).prop("checked", false) } )
```

Comment: You need to set the `checked` property of the `input`, not the `td`

Comment: When you say you want to uncheck them all, do you mean uncheck all and leave the last selected checked or do you really want them all to be unchecked.... like a deselect all?

Comment: I need really to uncheck all checkboxes in this row

Answer (score 2):

Problem with you implementation is that, You are setting `checked` property of `TD` element not `checkbox`.

You can directly use [`:checkbox` selector](https://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/), then set its `checked` property

```
$("#unlosta_line_1 :checkbox").prop("checked", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

`input` is the children of the `td`

```js
(function (){
$("#unlosta_line_1").children("td").each(function(i) {
      $(this).children('input').attr("checked", false)
      })
      })()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr id="unlosta_line_1">
  <td>
    <input id="unlosta_prop_id_1" name="unlosta_prop_id[1]" value="1"  type="checkbox"> Feld 1
  </td>

  <td>
    <input id="unlosta_prop_id_2" name="unlosta_prop_id[2]" value="2" type="checkbox"> Feld 2
  </td>

  <td>
    <input id="unlosta_prop_id_3" name="unlosta_prop_id[3]" value="3" type="checkbox"> Feld 3
  </td>
  <td>...and so on
    <td>
</tr>
</table>
```